# Why cwd in /proc/nautilus_pid/cwd always points to /home/username?

Tags: proc, nautilus, cwd

I wanted to check the current directory opened in nautilus window. I check the pid of nautilus, and symbolic link `proc/pid/cwd`, always points to home directory. Is this expected behaviour? If so thenhow to check the opened directory of nautilus from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus can open multiple windows from the same process, but a process has a single current directory, so Nautilus can't change its directory based on what it's displaying in its windows.

I can't think of a good reason for Nautilus to change its current directory anyway. What would be the point? When Nautilus needs to access a file in a directory, it can just construct the absolute path.

[What problem are you actually trying to solve?](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Does the title of a nautilus window show the full path? What if nautilus has opened multiple *tabs* to different directories in the same window?

Comment: @UncleBilly I don't think it does. I don't know if there's a sensible way, given a window id that is a Nautilus window, to find what directory it's showing. If you want something that lends itself well to automation, Gnome isn't your friend.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I wanted to go to the directory which is opened in nautilus ASAP. I can open new terminal there but I  want to work on my current terminal session.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav Why not copy the path (`Ctrl+L Ctrl+C`) and paste it in your existing terminal?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', that's possible, but there is no stupidity in it. :) BTW thanks for ctrl+L.